# AWS sam deploy failed : Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Max attempts exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

Just added a DynamoDB table to my `template.yaml` for my stack. Running `aws deploy` freezes for some time with message
`Waiting for changeset to be created..`
And after a few minutes fails with

> File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/1.26.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/samcli/lib/deploy/deployer.py", line 295, in wait_for_changeset
> reason = resp["StatusReason"]
> KeyError: 'StatusReason'

I'm not sure what I am missing, I believe the IAM for this user has all required permissions as well. I'm very new to AWS so any help would be appreciated.

My template.yaml is

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  bibbl.io

  Sample SAM Template for bibbl.io

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    Environment:
      Variables:
        TABLE_NAME: my-table


Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
  MyTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB:Table
    Properties:
      TableName: my-table
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: note_id
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: upload_uri
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: note_id
          KeyType: HASH
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        IndexName: "upload_uri"
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: "upload_uri"
            KeyType: "HASH"
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: "ALL"
        ProvisionedThroughput: 
          ReadCapacityUnits: 5
          WriteCapacityUnits: 5
      ProvisionedThroughput: 
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref MyTable


Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
  TableName:
    Value: !Ref MyTable
    Description: Table name of the newly created DynamoDB table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several mistakes in your template.yml.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  bibbl.io

  Sample SAM Template for bibbl.io

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    Environment:
      Variables:
        TABLE_NAME: my-table


Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref MyTable

  MyTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: my-table
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: note_id
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: upload_uri
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: note_id
          KeyType: HASH
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
       -
          IndexName: "upload_uri"
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: "upload_uri"
              KeyType: "HASH"
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: "ALL"
          ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 5
            WriteCapacityUnits: 5
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 5
        WriteCapacityUnits: 5


Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Fun ction ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
  TableName:
    Value: !Ref MyTable
    Description: Table name of the newly created DynamoDB table
```

1. The type for your Dynamo Table is missing a second colon after the **Dynamo**.
2. The `Policy` attribute needs to be on your Lambda, not on your table. You want to give the Lambda function access to you table and not your table to itself, which does not make sense.
3. `GlobalSecondaryIndexes` is a list of objects. You were missing the dash to indicate the start of a list.